# pushing (multidimensional) arrays to multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to convert my newsfeed result into an array, so that I can now group the results and have entries like "Peter and 6 others commented…"

I thought asking for other people, who commented on the same thread via in_array(); would be a good solution. But now I'm having a hard time converting my whole mysql result into an array without having to change my entire structure of the original while loop, where all the database values are requested with the $getnews_row. I think there might be a mistake in the way that I'm creating the arrays.

I spent the past hour googling my hands off, but I can't find any examples where a variable(array) is actually added to a multidimensional array.

Any ideas?

My PHP:

```
$x = 0;
while($getnews_row = mysql_fetch_array($res_getnews))
{
$this_getnewsrow = array
  (
  [$x] => array
  ($getnews_row)
  )
  $x++;
}

$x = $x_total;
$x=0;
while($x < $x_total)
{

    $getnews_row =  $this_getnewsrow[$x];

    echo $getnews_row['id'];

    x++;
}
```

My Output:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /newsfeed/index.php on line 48 (line 6 in this excerpt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize array this way.

Try replacing this

```
$x = 0;
while($getnews_row = mysql_fetch_array($res_getnews))
{
$this_getnewsrow = array
  (
  [$x] => array
  ($getnews_row)
  )
  $x++;
}
```

with this

```
while($getnews_row = mysql_fetch_array($res_getnews))
{
$this_getnewsrow[] = $getnews_row;
}
```

Take a look at [PHP: Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

---

Also try to replace `$x = $x_total;` with `$x_total = $x;`

And add `$` to `x` variable in the second loop.

Comment: doesn't work - i think the rows might be added to $this_getnewsrow, but the values can't be requested in the second while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$i = 0;
while($getnews_row = mysql_fetch_array ($res_getnews)) {
    $this_getnewsrow [$i] = $getnews_row;
    $i++;
}

$j = 0;
while($j < $i_total)
{

    $getnews_row =  $this_getnewsrow[$j];

    echo $getnews_row ['id'];

    $j++;
}
```

UPDATE

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res_getnews, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row ['id'];
}
```

Comment: the same problem - i think the rows might be added to $this_getnewsrow, but the values can't be requested in the second while loop.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, the code I put in under ÚPDATE should serve your purpose; give it a try! (just replace the whole code block you pasted in your question with that)

Comment: but doesn't this just simply get the values from mysql again? i'd rather like to read the arrays in the second while loop... when it comes to a lot of modifications within my $this_getnewsrow array, that's gonna save me a lot of time...